# GoogleOauth Redirect Request empty

Tags: reactjs, node.js, express, google-oauth

I'm trying to use Google oauth for my new node.js with React Application.

I've used the [google html generator](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/tools/configurator) to create the login button:

```
<div id="g_id_onload"
    data-client_id={GOOGLE_OAUTH_CLIENT_ID}
    data-context="signin"
    data-ux_mode="popup"
    data-login_uri={API_ENDPOINT_URL + "/auth/google"}
    data-auto_select="true"
    data-itp_support="true"
>
</div>
<div className="g_id_signin"
    data-type="standard"
    data-shape="pill"
    data-theme="outline"
    data-text="signin_with"
    data-size="large"
    data-logo_alignment="left"
>
</div>
```

the API_ENPOINT_URL is the following schema: https://mydomain.app

The api (server) code is the following currently:

```
app.post('/auth/google', (req, res) => {
        // exchange code for tokens
        console.log(req.body);
        console.log('body.code: ' + req.body.code);
        console.log('query.code: ' + req.query.code);
        console.log('body.credential: ' + req.body.credential);
        console.log('query.credential: ' + req.query.credential);
        //const { tokens } = await oAuth2Client.getToken(req.body.code);
        //console.log(tokens);
        //res.json(tokens);
        res.status(200).send();
});
```

The popup is opening fine, the POST request is being sent out as I can see it in the logs, but sadly I neither get a code or a credential from google?

Log output is like this:

```
{}
body.code: undefined
query.code: undefined
body.credential: undefined
query.credential: undefined
```

Any Idea what I'm missing here? Regarding googles docs the Post request should look like [this](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/reference/html-reference?hl=en#server-side)

All I could find using the debugger was the cookie from google with the g_csrf_token, but thats it.
No parameters at all.

Can someone help me?

Tried on local machine first, then went on development server with a https Webserver and a domain, but nothing changed, still same result. I've searched for hours online but couldn't find a solution

Comment: Finally found out what the problem was, my express Backend couldnt read the content of the request because `app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));` was missing. After adding that it worked now